# PHP-PFM is running after /etc/init.d/php5-fpm stop

Tags: php

I really do not understand why PFM daemon is running AFTER my stop.

This is ps aux:

```
root       998  0.1  0.1 127268  4316 ?        Ss   02:13   0:36 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
1004       999  0.0  0.1 127812  4628 ?        S    02:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
```

and this is the /etc/init.d/php5-fpm file

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          php-fpm php5-fpm
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: starts php-fpm
### END INIT INFO

set -u

DAEMON="PHP5 FPM"
FPM_CMD=/usr/sbin/php5-fpm
FPM_CONF=/etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
FPM_PID=/var/run/php5-fpm.pid
TIMEOUT=30

FPM_OPTIONS="--fpm-config $FPM_CONF"
SSD_OPTIONS="--oknodo --quiet --pidfile $FPM_PID --exec $FPM_CMD"

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
    start)
        log_begin_msg "Starting $DAEMON..."

        /sbin/start-stop-daemon --start $SSD_OPTIONS -- $FPM_OPTIONS
        log_end_msg $?
    ;;
    stop)
        log_begin_msg "Stopping $DAEMON..."

        /sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop $SSD_OPTIONS
        log_end_msg $?
    ;;
    graceful-stop)
        log_begin_msg "Gracefully stopping $DAEMON..."

        /sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --retry QUIT/$TIMEOUT/TERM $SSD_OPTIONS
        log_end_msg $?
    ;;
    restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
    ;;
    reload|force-reload)
        log_begin_msg "Reloading $DAEMON..."

        /sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR2 $SSD_OPTIONS
        log_end_msg $?
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|graceful-stop|restart|reload|force-reload}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Just to be sure, have you ran `/etc/init.d/php-fpm stop` as root?

Comment: I also stopped lighttpd, but nothing...still running. I don't understand why I have to kill the processese myself :( hmmm

Answer (score 2):

I know the post is a bit old by now but still theres a sollution

You can have php-fpm daemonize itself by setting the 
daemonize=yes in the php-fpm.conf

in the [global] block in the config file you can add or set the pid file for the daemon process by adding this line:
pid = /var/run/php-fpm.pid

then just have the start-stop-daemon not set the pid for the php-fpm process but instead use the pid provided by teh daemon itself

the init.d script for php-fpm would look like this then:

```
#!/bin/sh
NAME="php-fpm"
DESC="${NAME} deamon script"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
DAEMON="/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm"
DAEMON_OPTS="--fpm-config=/path/to/php-fpm.conf -c=/path/to/php.ini"
#set this file to the same file as in your php-fpm.conf
PIDFILE="/var/run/${NAME}.pid"
QUIET="--quiet"
START_OPTS="--start ${QUIET} --background --exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS}"
STOP_OPTS="--stop --pidfile ${PIDFILE}"

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

set -e

case "$1" in
        start)
                echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
                export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/"
                start-stop-daemon $START_OPTS
                echo "$NAME."
        ;;
        stop)
                echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
                start-stop-daemon $STOP_OPTS
                echo "$NAME."
        ;;
        restart)
                echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
                start-stop-daemon $STOP_OPTS
                sleep 1
                export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/"
                start-stop-daemon $START_OPTS
                echo "$NAME."
        ;;
        *)
                N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
                echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart}" >&2
                exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do `killall -9 php-fpm` and look for php-fpm logs. I suppose it hang processing long php script with `set_time_limit(0)` and `ignore_user_abort(true)` in it for example.